# Is it ambiguous in Apple Document when -[NSInputStream read:maxLength:] return 0?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In NSInputStream Apple Document, it states that when -[NSInputStream read:maxLength:] return 0,

> - 0 indicates that the end of the buffer was reached.

Is 'the buffer' referring to the buffer that user assigns to read parameter or the read buffer, a.k.a the stream itself.

If it refers to the first case, that means data filled up the user's buffer. It is possible that there may be more data to come.

If it refers to the latter case, that means no more data to come. So it is time to clean up.

This kind of ambiguity does waste people's time to figure it out.

Comment: Its not ambiguous, buffer you provide is a temp block of memory that NSStream fills in with data up to max length you provide. Also, there is no way for NSStream to find out the actual length of buffer that you pass along in 'read' parameter. Therefore it's obvious that it refers to stream buffer itself.

Comment: You set maxLength. Of course, NSStream can figure it out if it reach the end of provided buffer.

Comment: for the copy buffer, yes, it can but its really irrelevant in the context of this operation. You receive amount of bytes copied into provided buffer.

Answer (score 1):

It refers the stream buffer.  If the provided buffer is filled, the return value will be `len`.

Comment: No.  If the provided buffer *is filled*, the return value will be `len`.  Not _or less_.

Comment: sorry, you are right. I referred to `maxLength`, however you meant return value.

Comment: If provided buffer is filled, -[NSInputStream read:maxLength:] keeps on filling depending on if reach maxLength or availability of data in stream buffer. So it is possible that it leads to buffer overflow.

Comment: You can expect under flows but never overflows until you trick it by providing wrong (smaller) 'maxLength' than the actual allocated memory for copy buffer.